# How to execute a specific javascript file in a specific view in rails and webpack?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

so I am building an app with `rails` and `webpack`, and I got rid of `assets pipeline` and `sprockets`. So far, nothing exceptional.

I know that `webpack` throws all JavaScript files that lives in `app/javascript/packs` and the browser executes them all regardless of which `views` is actually loaded and this can causes errors.

What I am trying to do is to make the browser execute a specific `JavaScript` file for a specific `view`.

Example: if the view is `foo.html.erb`, the browser execute the JavaScript `foo.js` that lives in `~/app/javascript/packs` only when `foo.html.erb` called.

Remember that I am using webpack so putting the helper `<%= javascript_include_tag : 'foo'%>` will not work in my case since I work with webpack instead of the `assets pipeline`

Is there a simple and straightforward way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can read document here https://github.com/rails/webpacker and using helper:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Example. You create a `foo.js` at `~/app/javascript/packs`
You can call this file at view

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'foo' %>
```